# How to add a button with a Stage class that does not implement the Screen interface?

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering

I have my own Libgdx class that does not implement the Screen 
Interface. I control my camera movement. It's an orthographic camera whose viewport width is WorldWidth and viewport height is WorldHeight. I am trying to add a button via the Stage class. I am able to add it and I see that its drawn, but since I don't implement the screen interface I call stage.draw() on my render() method, not on the render(float delta) method that seems to be required by the Screen interface. For comparison purposes, I draw a sprite whose size is (0.25f*camera.viewportWidth,0.25f*camera.viewportHeight). However, this sprite is not drawing when I call stage.draw(). The button draws but it seems very small even though I set its size to (0.25f*camera.viewportWidth,0.25f*camera.viewportHeight). Here's the code on 
how I add my button class:

```
stage1= new Stage();
btn = new Button(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(new Texture("texone.png"))),
new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(new Texture("textwo.png"))));
btn.addListener(new ClickListener(){
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){ }
});
btn.setBounds(0f,0f,0.25f*camera.viewportWidth,0.25f*camera.viewportHeight);
btn.setPosition(0f,100f);
stage1.add(btn);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage1);
//a few lines down to my render() method
@Override
public void render(){
//.... more regular code that goes in method
batch.begin();
//more lines of code that draw my sprites
stage1.draw();
batch.end();
}
```

What I want to know is why is the button so small and why isn't my other sprite drawing? Perhaps there is a way to add my orthographic camera to my stage1 object. And, if I add my orthographic camera to my stage1 object, how should I update my stage1 viewport on the resize method? Please advise.

thank you

Comment: You can move stage1.draw() after batch.end(), it has it's own batch begin and end. When you create your stage, you can specify a viewport which will create a camera for it.

Comment: Man you are awesome! thanks for the right answer. @Barodapride

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you set a projection matrix for batch. Do you call this function?

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

you should do it in render function